# Cannot find System.Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a VS2010 project that needs a reference to System.Xaml.  I go to the Add Reference, search the .NET references and it's not there. :?

I double checked the GAC too, and no such luck.

I just can't figure out for the life of me why it's not on the machine.  This machine has .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.0 installed.

I'd much rather there be a simple explanation for this problem and not have to resort to reinstalling the framework. T-T

Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your project is probably targeting .Net 3.5, which does not have the required DLL.

You can set the Framework Version in Project Properties.

Comment: ugh...I'm such a n00b. Thanks. :)

Comment: Unless that target framework version is intentional, in which case it is the [reference that should be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7830416/1430156).

Answer (score 12):

On my machine it's located at

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xaml.dll
```

and it's available in the add references dialog as well (checked in a .Net4 target project, which might be your issue here).

Comment: Yep it's there.  Thanks. ^__^

I assumed it was introduced in .NET 3.5 x__x