# "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly in Silverlight project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update3.

My solution contains .NET Framework 4 projects and silverlight projects.
when I try to build silverlight projects,
I get error like this.

I read this article
[Cannot find System.Xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408544/cannot-find-system-xaml)
and found out I should target .Net 3.5 but how can I do for silverlight projects?

```
"CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: file or assembly 'XamlServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'XamlServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 'XamlServices, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Server stack trace: 
   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
    System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change .net platform in silverlight project because silverlight is standalone platform. You can change only Silverlight version from 4 to 5. But as you can read in Microsoft documentation namespace System.Xaml is very limited in silverlight (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml(v=vs.95).aspx).

Maybe you should consider write your code at the server side project where You can chose .NET framework >= 4 (.NET 3.5 does not have this DLL yet) and there namespace System.Xaml is more complex (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml(v=vs.100).aspx). To communicate Silverlight with server You can use RIA Services.